# File .sql sample-data in magento 2 in folder?

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I want to know the file sample-data.sql in magento 2 located in the folder?
thank you.

Comment: Check the ``/bin`` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 do not use sample data in sql format. Please use [sample data module](https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data).